# Intellij adding remote host: Session.connect: java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

I want to use SFTP to connect to my working machine available through VPN.

I'm not able to establish a connection inside PyCharm (IntelliJ for python), but instead I always get an error.

First, I checked that I can connect to the host with ssh and it's ok (and sftp on filezilla is working with same parameters and credentials).

In PyCharm I get:

```
Connection to <hostname> failed. 
Session.connect: java.net.UnknownHostException: <hostname>
```

I've also tried to use IPv6 address of server. This time the error is

```
java.net.SocketException: Protocol family unavailable
```

while again from SSH and filezilla everything is ok.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this bug is documented:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-26878

The temporary solution is (below given for webstorm, but for other IDEs you need replace name/version)

```
cp /Applications/WebStorm.app/Contents/bin/webstorm.vmoptions ~/Library/Preferences/WebStorm10/
vim ~/Library/Preferences/WebStorm10/webstorm.vmoptions
```

And add following lines to the file:

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true
```